# Passar inputs de innerHTML para form e acessar via PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho um formulário HTML, campos de input normais, botão de submit... Através de uma função JS, adiciono à uma DIV (com innerHTML), campos input adicionais.

```
var div = document.getElementById('produtos-adicionados');
div.innerHTML = '<input type='text' class='form-control' name='item' id='item' required='' />';
```

Quando der o submit no formulário, não consigo acessar esse novo input de name item, obviamente.

De que forma conseguiria enviar o formulário e obter o value do input no php? Além de, ao enviar o formulário, conseguir obter também os valores dos demais inputs, que estão no formulário mas não estão no innerHTML.

Comment: Todos inputs adicionais usam o `name=item`, de forma repetida?

Comment: esse comando `div.innerHTML = '...'` funciona com todas essas aspas simples?

Comment: Os names dos inputs gero dinâmicamente e com um contador vou incrementando. Exemplo: primeiro input terá o seguinte name: item0. O seguinte, se chamará item1, e assim sucessivamente. Mesma coisa para outros, onde tenho: quantidade0, quantidade1, etc...

Comment: div.innerHTML funciona com as aspas simples por que o comando uso com aspas duplas. Ex: div.innerHTML = "<input type='text' />"

Comment: O elemento de `id="produtos-adicionados"` está dentro do `<form></form>`?

Comment: Sim, está dentro do form.

Answer (score -1):

Atente:

1. uso de aspas em volta do html
2. atributo required não necessita de atribuir valor

Atualização:

Usando o jQuery para mostrar que o input adicionado fazer parte do form.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('produtos-adicionados');
div.innerHTML = "Apelido: <input type='text' class='form-control' name='item' id='item' required />"

$('#myform').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  alert(JSON.stringify(($('#myform').serializeArray())))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form id="myform" action="/action_page.php">
  Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" required>
  <div id="produtos-adicionados"> substituir conteúdo</div>

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```